# HAML error, ruby 1.9.3 on rails 3. syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, expecting $end

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I keep on receiving this error:

```
Showing app/views/posts/index.html.haml where line #115 raised:

app/views/posts/index.html.haml:115: syntax error, unexpected keyword_ensure, 
expecting $end

Extracted source (around line #115):

0

Trace of template inclusion: app/views/posts/index.html.haml

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace

app/controllers/posts_controller.rb:28:in `index'
```

This is the index.html.haml file:

```
.container-fluid
%br 
.row-fluid 
    .span3 
        .well.sidebar-nav{:style=>'background-color:rgb(999,999,999);'}
            %ul.nav.nav-pills.nav-stacked 
                %li
                    %a{:href => '#'} Todays Best 
                %li 
                    %a{:href => '#'} Yesterdays Best 
                %li 
                    %a{:href => '#'} Weeks Best 
                %li 
                    %a{:href => '#'} Months Best 
                %li 
                    %a{:href => '#'} Hall of Fame 
        .label.label-inverse
            %center
                Todays Best: 
        %table.table.table-bordered.table-condensed{:style=>'background-color:rgb(999,999,999);'}
            - @count= 0
            - @feedcount= 4 #5 best
            - @popularfeed.each do |post|
                - if @count<=@feedcount then
                    %tr
                        %td
                            %center
                                =  truncate(post.content, :length => 132)
                                -  @count= @count +1
                                %br
                            %p{:align => "right"}
                                %span{:style=>'color:green;'}=post.likes
                                %span{:style=>'color:red;'}=post.dislikes
                                %span{:style=>'color:blue;'}=post.prominence
    .span6 
        %center
            %table.table.table-bordered.table-condensed{:style=>'background-color:rgb(999,999,999);'}
            - @mainfeed.each do |post|
                =link_to post do 
                    %tr
                        %td  
                            %center
                                %br
                                =post.content   
                            %p.small{:align => 'right'}
                                3 days ago
                            %center  



                                %span.labelStyle.label.label-success
                                    =link_to 'Agree', :action  =>   'like', :id  =>   post.id
                                    =post.likes 
                                %span.label.label-important.postbar 
                                    =link_to 'Disagree', :action  =>   'dislike', :id  =>   post.id
                                    =post.dislikes 
                                %span.label.label-info.postbar 
                                    =link_to 'Voice', :action => 'prominence', :id  =>  post.id
                                    =post.prominence
                                %span.label.postbar 
                                    %a{:'data-toggle'=>"modal", :'data-target'=>"#myModal"}
                                        Comments
                                        =post.comments.count

                                %span.label.postbar 
                                    Report
                                %br 
                                %br 
                                %tr
                    %td
                        %p
                            %a.btn{:href => '#'} View details &raquo; 
    .span3
        .well{:style=>'background-color:rgb(999,999,999);'}
            =render 'form'  
        -#  .alert.alert-success 
        -#      Post was succesfully made.
    .span3
        .label.label-inverse
            %center Most Controversial:                  
        %table.table.table-bordered.table-condensed{:style=>'background-color:rgb(999,999,999);'}
            - @count= 0            
            - @feedcount= 3  #3 best 
            - @controfeed.each do |post|
                - if @count<=@feedcount then  
                    %tr                                 
                        %td                                       
                            %center                                         
                                =truncate(post.content, :length => 132)             
                                -@count= @count +1
                                %br                                                     
                            %p{:align => "right"}
                                %span{:style=>'color:green;'}=post.likes              
                                %span{:style=>'color:red;'}=post.dislikes     
                                %span{:style=>'color:blue;'}=post.prominence
```

I believe the error should be in .span6 but i am not sure. This file is only 112 lines long and the error is on line 115. help is appreciated

Comment: The code looks ok. Chop it in half and find the lines with the error. Then chop again until you find the exact place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two comments (or at least, I think you were commenting in your code) on 116 and 177 that are not prefixed by `-`

`#3 best` and `#5 best` may need to become `-#3best` and `-#5best`